# Set-Acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation while using Addaudit Rule

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I am trying to run Powershell script to set Audit Rule on C:\Windows\security folder on my Windows 2008 box.

Below is the script:

```
$FileDirList = ("C:\Windows\security")

$AccountName     = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Everyone") 
$FileSystemRight = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
$AuditFlag       = [System.Security.AccessControl.AuditFlags]::Failure
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None

#
#write-OSPBOSbuildLog  "Applying Audit Setting"
#     

foreach ($FileDirName in $FileDirList) {   
    #write-OSPBOSbuildLog  ">>>>>  Appying audit setting to $FileDirName"

    $AuditRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule $AccountName, $FileSystemRight, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $AuditFlag 

    $objACL = Get-ACL $FileDirname 

    $objACL.AddAuditRule($AuditRule)

    Set-ACL $FileDirname $objACL
}
```

But I am getting error as shown below:

> ```
> Set-Acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
> At C:\IBM\File-Perm.ps1:22 char:12
> +     Set-ACL <<<<  $FileDirname $objACL
>     + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows:String) [Set-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
> ```

Please help me understand what changes I need to do?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: 1) Your `$FileDirList` is an array that contains a single string. It seems more like you intend it to contain a list of filenames in that directory. 2) It is likely you need to launch PowerShell elevated (right-click, `Run as administrator`).

Comment: 1) I have added two parameters under $FileDirList and tested.    2) Already running PS as administrator. No luck